# Google sheets, how do I get regexmatch to find a text string in a list?

Tags: string, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match

I am new here, I have tried search for this answer and I can't find the same question

I am a totally self taught spreadsheet-maker, so if I have done some weird stuff - Please don't judge too harshly!

So I am using REGEXMATCH, and it just doesn't seem to be working like it usually does, and I can't work out why.

```
=IF($A13="","",(IF(REGEXMATCH({$L$13:$L$18},$A13),"YES","NO")))
```

I have made a workbook example to show the dilemma-

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1paNG9Q-AciYbIR3HSgW7vxqNJmJBexgpm2lkLn32PN8/edit?usp=sharing

I want each line to tell me if its CODE-ID is in a list of items. I am pretty sure I had this working at some point, but I can't remember what I have changed. The regexmatch seems to just be picking up whether the code is in the first cell of the list.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong? I want the YES/NO column to change as I add new CODE-IDs to the list.

The weird thing is, I have got other cells to work by breaking the code right down to the basic regexmatch formula and building it up again, but it wont replicate when I copy it to another line. I don't know how to show that in this example because it isn't working here.

Let me know if this makes sense,

Thank you kindly,

Ellie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in `I13`:

```
=INDEX(IF(A13:A="",,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A13:A, L13:L18, 0)), "YES", "NO")))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, amazing, this has worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this array formula. No need to drag down to each cell.

```
=ArrayFormula(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A13:A18,L13:L18,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this Harun24hr, It was the basis of what I needed, and Player0 added in the extra bits I needed with YES/NO etc. Thank you!